# The network interfaces don't work in static configuration in Debian Squeeze/Jessie on ARM platform

Tags: debian, network-interface, arm

I have trouble with a static configuration of the network interfaces in the Debian system on the `armel` platform.
With DHCP all goes fine.

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

The system gets an IP address, and the network works fine.
But when I have changed the config to the static one:

```
auto eth1
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.255.55.34
netmask 255.255.255.252
```

The network interface has stopped work in one state. It always switches from ON state to OFF and reverse.
Has anybody have this problem?

Comment: You have a typo in your config `eth1` <-> `eth0`

Answer (score 0):

You must add **allow-hotplug** statement and indent configuration. **You have a misconfiguration between eth0 and eth1 in your config.**

Your config:

```
auto **eth1**
iface **eth0** inet static
address 10.255.55.34
netmask 255.255.255.252
```

right config:

```
auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
        iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.255.55.34
        netmask 255.255.255.252
```